# Unable to understand percentage change monitor

Tags: alert, metrics, datadog

I am using Datadog to create alerts for a metric whose percentage change needs to be monitored for the past 2 days. The issue is I can't understand the evaluation window and comparison window mentioned in the monitor.

Is this correct for comparing the current day's data with the previous day's data?
[image]
For example:

Day 1 metric value=100
Day 2 metric value=120

(Considering the metric publishes data once in a day)

The percentage change should be (120-100)/100 * 100 = 20%

Answer (score 0):

With the configuration you provide, I believe Datadog would do something like this:

1. Query a time series of data from 2 days ago to now.
2. Query a time series of data from 3 days ago to 1 day ago.
3. Take the point-wise difference between the series from (1) and (2), yielding another time series.
4. Sum all the values in that time series.
5. Compare that value to the threshold you set.

It seems like the UI is missing a word like "before" at the end of that sentence.

If you want to get the calculation you laid out, you should select "average", "% change", "1 day" and "1 day."